# Performing a dplyr full_join without a common variable to blend data frames

Tags: r, dplyr

Using the dplyr `full_join()` operation, I am trying to perform the equivalent of a basic `merge()` operation in which no common variables exist (unable to satisfy the "by=" argument). This will blend two data frames and return all possible combinations.

However, the current `full_join()` function requires a common variable. I am unable to locate another dplyr function that can help with this. **How can I perform this operation using functions specific to the dplyr library?**

```
df_a = data.frame(department=c(1,2,3,4))
df_b = data.frame(period=c(2014,2015,2016,2017))

#This works as desired
big_df = merge(df_a,df_b)

#I'd like to perform the following in a much bigger operation:
big_df = dplyr::full_join(df_a,df_b)

#Error: No common variables. Please specify `by` param.
```

Comment: This is kind of a stupid method but you could make a variable on each side that is constant and merge on that... `df_a$dummy = 1` `df_b$dummy = 1` and then merge on `dummy`

Comment: Yes, that is suboptimal, but so far it appears to be the only way using only `dplyr`.

Comment: There's actually an [open issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2924) on adding cross-join functionality to dplyr

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `crossing` from `tidyr`:

```
crossing(df_a,df_b)

   department period
1           1   2014
2           1   2015
3           1   2016
4           1   2017
5           2   2014
6           2   2015
7           2   2016
8           2   2017
9           3   2014
10          3   2015
11          3   2016
12          3   2017
13          4   2014
14          4   2015
15          4   2016
16          4   2017
```

Comment: This solution only works if `df_a` and `df_b` each only consists of a single column.

Comment: @jarauh `tidyr::crossing()` does work when `df_a` has multiple columns, per the following example:
`df_a <- data.frame( x=1:4, y=1:4 ); `

`df_b <- data.frame( z=5:8 ); `

`tidyr::crossing( df_a, df_b )`

Comment: @bmosov01 I confirm.  Either I was wrong, or it did not work with an older version of `tidyr`.

Comment: Used the crossing method to mash two df's together and it worked perfect! Great solution.

Answer (score 0):

If there are duplicate rows, `crossing` doesn't give the same result as `merge`.

Instead use `full_join` with `by = character()` to perform a cross-join which generates all combinations of `df_a` and `df_b`.

```r
library("tidyverse") # version 1.3.2

# Add duplicate rows for illustration.
df_a <- tibble(department = c(1, 2, 3, 3))
df_b <- tibble(period = c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2017))
```

`merge` doesn't de-duplicate.

```r
df_a_merge_b <- merge(df_a, df_b)
df_a_merge_b
#>    department period
#> 1           1   2014
#> 2           2   2014
#> 3           3   2014
#> 4           3   2014
#> 5           1   2015
#> 6           2   2015
#> 7           3   2015
#> 8           3   2015
#> 9           1   2016
#> 10          2   2016
#> 11          3   2016
#> 12          3   2016
#> 13          1   2017
#> 14          2   2017
#> 15          3   2017
#> 16          3   2017
```

`crossing` drops duplicate rows.

```r
df_a_crossing_b <- crossing(df_a, df_b)
df_a_crossing_b
#> # A tibble: 12 × 2
#>    department period
#>         <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1          1   2014
#>  2          1   2015
#>  3          1   2016
#>  4          1   2017
#>  5          2   2014
#>  6          2   2015
#>  7          2   2016
#>  8          2   2017
#>  9          3   2014
#> 10          3   2015
#> 11          3   2016
#> 12          3   2017
```

`full_join` doesn't remove duplicates either.

```r
df_a_full_join_b <- full_join(df_a, df_b, by = character())
df_a_full_join_b
#> # A tibble: 16 × 2
#>    department period
#>         <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1          1   2014
#>  2          1   2015
#>  3          1   2016
#>  4          1   2017
#>  5          2   2014
#>  6          2   2015
#>  7          2   2016
#>  8          2   2017
#>  9          3   2014
#> 10          3   2015
#> 11          3   2016
#> 12          3   2017
#> 13          3   2014
#> 14          3   2015
#> 15          3   2016
#> 16          3   2017

packageVersion("tidyverse")
#> [1] '1.3.2'
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>